# Updating elemint in JSON updates ALL

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object parsed and I am trying to navigate down to SHIPPINGCOMMENTS and update it, but when I do, it updates all cells with that name instead of just the one.

```
{
    "id": 1402846607011,
    "status": "unsaved",
    "accounts": [
        {
            "compid": 919759,
            "compname": null,
            "products": [
                {
                    "BCINUM": "539504",
                    "ITEMUNIT": "EA",
                    "ORDERDETAILS": [
                        {
                            "SHIPDATEID": "69230",
                            "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                            "QUANTITY": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "SHIPDATEID": "69231",
                            "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                            "QUANTITY": "2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SHIPPINGCOMMENTS": "sooner"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "compid": 920001,
            "compname": null,
            "products": [
                {
                    "BCINUM": "539504",
                    "ITEMUNIT": "EA",
                    "ORDERDETAILS": [
                        {
                            "SHIPDATEID": "69230",
                            "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                            "QUANTITY": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "SHIPDATEID": "69231",
                            "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                            "QUANTITY": "2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "POTEXT": "",
                    "SHIPPINGCOMMENTS": "sooner"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code I am looping through it with:

```
function updateComments(compID,bcinum,comment) {
    var accounts = runningOrders.accounts;
    var n = accounts.length;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (accounts[i].compid == compID) {
            var p = accounts[i].products.length;
            for (ii = 0; ii < p; ii++) {
                if (accounts[i].products[ii].BCINUM == bcinum) {
                    accounts[i].products[ii].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS = comment;
                }   
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

The function call is:

```
updateComments(919759,539504,sooner);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything like what you describe. http://jsfiddle.net/KZaLz/

Comment: Your code is working for me. Only SHIPPINGCOMMENTS under compid 919759 and BCINUM 539504 gets updated. Maybe we need to see more of your code.

Comment: The only way your code could do what you describe is if all the objects referenced in the `products` arrays are references to the same object. Objects are not copied on assignment in JS. However, you say this is JSON, and JSON doesn't translate object references, so if that's the case, you're excluding some very relevant code.

Comment: Your right guys, it works exactly as I am expecting it to on your example on jsfiddle. So it must be an issue with the way I am creating these data structures. While I said JSON, it is manually constructed JS arrays and hash tables. Not sure how I can post additional code here in this thread. I just start with runningOrders = {}; then runningOrders.accounts = [];
runningOrders.accounts.products = []; and then I create objects and push them to the accounts and products array. Seems like the objects are one in the same even though I create them separately.

Comment: This is also happening to me for any update I make. An update I make in one element makes the update on all elements with the same key.

Comment: Maybe this is it. One thing about this ordering process UI, they are selecting multiple accounts first, and then every product they select after that is added for all accounts. I build an object called thisProductSelected and then loop over and push it to all accounts. 
var a = runningOrders.accounts.length;
for (var ii = 0;ii<a; ii++) {
 currAccount = runningOrders.accounts[ii];
 currAccount.products.push(thisProductSelected); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Two potential issues:

1. When calculating n, you are actually not calculating the size of the acconts array? What is the name of your (JSON) object?
2. In your example function call, you are changing the name to the already defined name in both objects. Is this a mistake?

This code is working for me in node.js:

```
function updateComments(compID,bcinum,comment) {
  var n = accounts.accounts.length;
  console.log(n);
  console.log(accounts['accounts'][0].products);
  console.log(accounts['accounts'][1].products);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log('testing ', i, accounts.accounts[i].compid)
    if (accounts.accounts[i].compid == compID) {
      var p = accounts.accounts[i].products.length;
      console.log('Found compid', i, compID);
      for (ii = 0; ii < p; ii++) {
        if (accounts.accounts[i].products[ii].BCINUM == bcinum) {
          console.log('Found bcinum', ii, bcinum)
          accounts.accounts[i].products[ii].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS = comment;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(accounts['accounts'][0].products);
  console.log(accounts['accounts'][1].products);
}

accounts = {
"id": 1402846607011,
"status": "unsaved",
"accounts":
 [
    {
        "compid": 919759,
        "compname": null,
        "products": [
            {
                "BCINUM": "539504",
                "ITEMUNIT": "EA",
                "ORDERDETAILS": [
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69230",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69231",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "SHIPPINGCOMMENTS": "sooner"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "compid": 920001,
        "compname": null,
        "products": [
            {
                "BCINUM": "539504",
                "ITEMUNIT": "EA",
                "ORDERDETAILS": [
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69230",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69231",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "POTEXT": "",
                "SHIPPINGCOMMENTS": "sooner"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: 1. The name of the JSON object is runningOrders, so I changed your reference of "accounts.accounts" to "runningOrders.accounts" and I used your function and I get the same result. 2. This one sounds like the issue I am having. I do not want to change the key SHIPPINGCOMMENTS value in both objects, only the one I am navigating to. This JSON object snapshot was taken after I updated the first one to "Sooner".

Comment: @Dan: His point 2 is just observing that your question appears as though you're trying to set the value to `"sooner"` when all the values are already `"sooner"`. Your question failed to state that the JSON markup provided represents the snapshot *after* the function call.

Comment: @Dan: If you add the same prints as I did, whats the output?

Comment: @cookie monster, thanks, I understand now. I did fail to state that this is a snapshot after my updated and displays the undesired behavior.

Comment: @civing - when I use your function after replacing "accounts.accounts" with "runningOrders.accounts" and I do an update on the first account, both runningOrders['accounts'][0].products[0].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS and runningOrders['accounts'][1].products[0].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS are updated to sooner.

Comment: I was able to resolve this over on another post: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254159/setting-array-element-changes-all-elements-with-same-name